# Cannot find the x and y angles. Is there something about the congruent lines in the two triangles that i need to use to find the answer?

Tags: geometry

[image: https://imgur.com/a/gEuOtTz]

Got the triangle on the left as 60° 60° 60° and the middle angle at the bottom is 46° but that's about it. What am I missing to get X and Y?

Comment: Hint - there's a pair of congruent triangles here by SAS.

Answer (score 1):

Since the segments marked with a red | are the same length, the other two (nonequiangular) triangles in the picture are both isosceles.

$\Delta QST$ isosceles means both of the unknown angles in it have the same measure (i.e. both are $x^\circ$).  Thus, $x^\circ + x^\circ + 74^\circ = 180^\circ$.  Solving gives $x^\circ = 53^\circ$.

$\Delta QSP$ isosceles means the angles opposite its congruent sides are congruent angles, so you can find the unknown angles in $\Delta QSP$ using similar reasoning.

Bottom line:  If you know any one of the angles in an isosceles triangle you can figure out the other two.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially missing the fact the sum of the inner angles of any triangle equals $180°$.

Notice that $y° = 180° - 2\times(180° - 60° - 74°) = 180° - 2\times 46° = 88°$.

Hence the right answer is given by the letter (B).

Hopefully this helps!

**EDIT**

To begin with, notice that
\begin{align*}
\angle PQR + \angle PQS + \angle SQT = 180° \Rightarrow \angle PQS & = 180° - \angle PQR - \angle SQT\\\\
& = 180° - 60° - 74° = 46°
\end{align*}

That is because the triangle $\Delta PRQ$ is equiangular and the angle $\angle SQT$ is given.

Since the triangle $\Delta SPQ$ is isosceles, it results that $\angle PQS = \angle QPS = 46°$.

Based on such information, one concludes that $y° = 180° - 2\times 46° = 88°$, and we are done.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. However, I'm still lost. I understand that triangles always consist of 3 angles totaling 180°. I'm not seeing where you are getting the 60° nor do I understand the ×2 multiplier. Is there something in the congruence of the three lines that I'm missing?

Comment: @dylancooney I have edited my answer. If you still have any difficulty, let me know.

Comment: Oh good Lord. I don't know how I forgot the isosceles rule. Thank you so much! I need to take a break. Haha

Comment: @dylancooney you are welcome! I am glad to help.

Comment: @dylancooney you can upvote/choose my answer if you think it deserves.